WTelegram Client - Pending Updates After Filled Gaps Issue
I have an issue when reading messages from a channel. The message has already arrived in the channel, but when I use WTelegram, I cannot see the message due to this issue:

Trying to apply 2 pending updates after filled gaps
UpdateEditChannelMessage
Trying to apply 1 pending update after filled gaps
Trying to recover gaps for 2 pending updates (2360819976, new +0->14)
TL.UpdateReadChannelInbox
First appearance of MBox
Trying to apply 2 pending updates after filled gaps

The above lines are console logs. How can I fix the filled gaps?

Don't open BOTH a StackOverflow question and a github issue https://github.com/wiz0u/WTelegramClient/issues/300
